# CLOS: Method combination with arbitrary function

Tags: oop, common-lisp, language-design, clos, method-combination

While reading about CLOS (in *ANSI Common Lisp* by Paul Graham), I noticed that there are nine functions that can be given to `defmethod` as its second argument:
`+`, `and`, `append`, `list`, `max`, `min`, `nconc`, `or` and `progn`.  According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787217/difference-between-the-standard-method-combination-and-simple-method-combinat), they are called *simple method combinations*.

#### Question

Why only these nine? What is the reason I cannot pass an arbitrary function as the second argument?

#### Example of what I would like

Suppose I defined `xor` as

```
(defun xor (&rest args)
   (loop for a in args counting (not (null a)) into truths
      finally (return (= truths 1))))
```

(this could certainly be improved). I would like to define several classes describing clothes and their combinations using `xor`:

```
(defgeneric looks-cool (x)
   (:method-combination xor))

(defclass black-trousers () ())
(defclass quilt () ())
(defclass white-shirt () ())
(defclass hawaii-shirt () ())

(defmethod looks-cool xor ((tr black-trousers)) nil)
(defmethod looks-cool xor ((qu quilt)) t)
(defmethod looks-cool xor ((ws white-shirt)) nil)
(defmethod looks-cool xor ((hs hawaii-shirt)) t)

(defclass too-stiff (black-trousers white-shirt) ())
(defclass scottish  (quilt white-shirt) ())
(defclass also-good (black-trousers hawaii-shirt) ())
(defclass too-crazy (quilt hawaii-shirt) ())
```

Now if this compiled (which it doesn't), I would be able to use Lisp to guide me as to what to wear:

```
> (looks-cool (make-instance 'too-stiff))
  NIL
> (looks-cool (make-instance 'scottish))
  T
> (looks-cool (make-instance 'also-good))
  T
> (looks-cool (make-instance 'too-crazy))
  NIL
```

I am well aware that this is a rather artificial example of no practical importance. Still, I would like to know whether there is some deeper reason behind or whether the restriction to the nine functions is just to make implementation easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the standard Common Lisp macro [DEFINE-METHOD-COMBINATION](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defi_4.htm#define-method-combination) to define your own *simple method combinations*:

Example:

```
(define-method-combination xor :identity-with-one-argument t)
```

Then:

```
CL-USER 5 > (mapcar #'looks-cool
                    (list (make-instance 'too-stiff)
                          (make-instance 'scottish)
                          (make-instance 'also-good)
                          (make-instance 'too-crazy)))
(NIL T T NIL)
```

If we look at `(define-method-combination xor :identity-with-one-argument t)`, it has several meanings for the name `xor`:

- it uses an *operator* `xor` - a function, macro or special form - not only functions are allowed. If the operator name should be different from the method combination name -> use the `:operator` keyword to specify that.
- it defines a *method combination* named `xor`. This name can be used in `defgeneric`.
- it defines a *method qualifier* `xor`. This can be used in `defmethod`.

Note that one can also define more complex method combinations with that `DEFINE-METHOD-COMBINATION`.